# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - Error during hourly process for push notifications

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

We're getting an error in WebSphere's `SystemOut` log approximately every hour on our Worklight Server.

It seems to be trying to validate push notification configuration.  We currently have working notifications, using Apple push notifications only. Errors are:

> com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsFeedbackConnection getInactiveDevices
>   Failed to retreive invalid devices ava.lang.RuntimeException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Our notifications are working, but, what is this hourly process? I don't see anything in the docs regarding a batch process that's run by Worklight Server.

Our setup: Worklight Server 6.0.0.20130909-1459, WAS 8.0.0.6, JDK 1.6.

Comment: Please add the complete stack of the exception, it looks to me like you have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Worklight uses notnoop open source library to push notification to APNS. This is a known harmless bug in notnoop.

https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/issues/29

Answer (score 0):

I believe this check is part of the way APNS's feedback service works.

From: [Provider Communication with Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3)
Section: General Provider Requirements

> Connect regularly with the feedback service and fetch the current list
>   of those devices that have repeatedly reported failed-delivery
>   attempts. Then stop sending notifications to the devices associated
>   with those applications. See “[The Feedback Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3)” for more
>   information.

As for what it means, it looks to me like your exception quote is cut. Is that all of it?

Comment: Can't post the entire error, stackoverflow.com only allows 600 chars.  How do you want me to send it to you?